# indices of all occurrences of all elements

Tags: python, list

given a list I would like to see indices of all occurrences of all elements in a dictionary. I am looking for the Python implementation of function [group](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dictsandtables/#group) offered by the Q programming language. I am expecting a simpler solution than code below

```
l=[2, 1, 1, 7, 2]

d={}
for e, v in enumerate(l):
    if v in d.keys():
        d[v].append(e)
    else:
        d[v]= [e]

print(d)

{2: [0, 4], 1:[1, 2], 7: [3]}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.  What's the problem with it?  Just put this in a function `def group(it):` and you're done.

Comment: Can simplify `v in d.keys()` to `v in d` (which is also very important for performance if you happen to use Python 2, but don’t use Python 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to smoothen your code, but other than that, it's fine:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    d[x].append(i)
```

Alternativey, you can use the [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to access `dict` values:

```
d = {}
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(i)
```